# UIComponent Form - Spinner showing

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, ui-form, crud

In my Form UIComponent only a spinner is showing. I compared my implementation to several ways it is implemented. The grid is showing just fine, i only have the problem in the form.

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="offertool_offer_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My offertool_offer_form.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">remklov_offertool_form.offer_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">remklov_offertool_form.offer_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">offertool_offer_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="offer_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Remklov\OfferTool\Ui\DataProvider\Form\OfferDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">offer_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="General">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="quote_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Quote ID</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Offer</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">quote_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Remklov\OfferTool\Ui\DataProvider\Form;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Remklov\OfferTool\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\CollectionFactory;

class OfferDataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory $collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var $_loadedData
     */
    protected $_loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();

        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->_loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }

        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}
```

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- OFFER DATA PROVIDER -->
    <preference for="Remklov\OfferTool\Api\OfferRepositoryInterface" type="Remklov\OfferTool\Model\OfferRepository"/>
    <preference for="Remklov\OfferTool\Api\Data\OfferInterface" type="Remklov\OfferTool\Model\Offer"/>
    <preference for="Remklov\OfferTool\Api\Data\OfferSearchResultsInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults"/>

    <type name="Remklov\OfferTool\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">offer_entity</argument>
            <argument name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Remklov\OfferTool\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\Grid\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="offer_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Remklov\OfferTool\Model\ResourceModel\Offer\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

If i print the array of returned data, this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [previous_id] => 
            [increment_id] => 
            [quote_id] => 36
            [sales_staff_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2019-07-06 14:40:10
            [updated_at] => 2019-07-06 14:40:10
        )

)
```

I get no error, and just the page title (and if added the buttons) are shown.

Comment: Show me please di.xml

Comment: I updated my question and added the di.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change these nodes (`provider`, `deps` )to this format: **{file_name}.{file_name}_data_source**.