# How to Debug UI Component only showing spinner

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

I am currently developing a customer AdminHtml page with a form, and after fixing some other errors (which showed error messages) it shows only the spinner when loading the page.

How can this be debugged further? How can I see a proper error message?

Browser Console and Logs are showing nothing of value.

I already found

[UIComponent Form - Spinner showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281052/uicomponent-form-spinner-showing)

[Magento 2: Spinner kept running and not showing data after creating custom admin grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294505/magento-2-spinner-kept-running-and-not-showing-data-after-creating-custom-admin)

but I want to know how to debug this instead of posting my code on StackExchange and let somebody else debug this.

Is there any way to get a proper error message?

Comment: There is one ajax call fires in all types of UI component grids. It's url contains path like "mui/index/render/". You can check this call in console under network. You should be getting some error in the response of this ajax/api call. Please check.

Comment: @PratikNavapara Good point, but no, there is no such AJAX call related to my form.

Comment: I found there seems to be some logging, but it's hidden. Trying to activate it with `require(['lib/logger/console-logger', 'lib/logger/levels-pool'], function(logger, levels) { logger.setDisplayLevel(levels.ALL)} );` but no luck so far

Comment: If you are not getting exact error then you can try alternative ways like commenting some ui xml file (grid/form) code step by step and try to find the piece of the code which is responsible for the issue you are getting. This might help you further.

Comment: @PratikNavapara I got the error reporting working, see answer :)

Comment: That's really good to know..

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to dig into component initialization (via https://twitter.com/vova_yatsyuk/status/1250807165914357762)

There actually is logging with console-logger in place, but it is disabled by default.

If you open your JavaScript console and type:

```
require(['Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger', 
   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/levels-pool'], 
           function(logger, levels) { 
                logger.setDisplayLevel(2) // 2 = WARN 5 = ALL, see levels-pool.js
           }
);
```

the logging is enabled (stored in local storage). You can reload your page and will get log output from the component loading.

There should be warnings about components which were requested but not loaded.

Also be aware, that the spinner seems to be replaced with the columns entry when doing listings, so another reason the spinner stays, can be a missing entry like that

```
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">my_listing_columns</item>
```